# Android connection to invalid Web-service makes application hang

Tags: android, web-services, freeze

My application connects to the web-service using ksoap2. The application enables the user to change the IP address/URL of the server which gives the web-service (in settings).

The problem is that when the user changes the IP address/URL to an invalid location, the application hangs for a long time and the LogCat shows that the application was unable to connect to the Socket description provided.

How do I fix this ? How do I stop the application from hanging if the Web-service is not found ?

I want the app UI to remain as it is if the web-service is not found. Is there any way to avoid the application from hanging ?

This is my code. Please suggest any means to avoid the application from hanging.

```
 private void getControlFromServer()  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_GET_CONTROL);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
        new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);




     try {
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GET_CONTROL, envelope);




            SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //To get the data.

            tvTemp.setText("Received :" + result.getProperty(0).toString()+ " : " + result.getProperty(1).toString() +  " : " + result.getProperty(2).toString() +  " : " + result.getProperty(3).toString() +  " : " + result.getProperty(4).toString() +  " : " + result.getProperty(5).toString() +  " : " + result.getProperty(6).toString());

     } catch (Exception e) {


            tvTemp.setText("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


}
```

Comment: Use connectionTimeOut with your webservice call.

Comment: Can you please provide the code snippet ?

Comment: is this code running in separated thread?

Comment: @MoshErsan : My code works fine when the URL is correct. But, if it is wrong, then the application hangs for about 30 seconds.

Comment: @swayam did you test your app on device/emulator with API > 10?

Comment: @Selvin : Yeah. My emulator is for 4.0.3 and so is my application. Anyway, the problem has been solved with the code in the answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **ConnectionTimeOut** to your `HttpTransportSE` object..

Use latest Use [ksoap2 API version 2.5.7](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2) or greater,

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;
SoapObject response = null;

try {
        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,6000); // Tried Setting the Timeout to 1 Minute
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm now. I was already using ksoap2 version 2.6.5. Only had to add the parameter to the newHttpTansportSE().